# How can I create a notification when a user receives new message from another user in my chat?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-notifications

I have a chat in my Android Application. Through this chat, users in my application are able to communicate with each other via text.

When a user ("Zoey") sends a message to another user ("Fred"), I want Fred to get notified about that, even if the app on Fred's device is closed at the time that Zoey sent her message.

I've tried To create a service which basically supposes to listen each time a change on my data base reference has been done.

```java
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      //     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"service  created: "+staticUSERNAME,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        databaseReference =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notifications");
        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        createNotificationChannels();
        addUserStateListener();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"service  started ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //add5();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void addUserStateListener() {
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATE CHANGED.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

this will guarantie the Notification will be delivered when App is in background.
if you use a service and system gets killed the app, under circumstances service will not start again and notification will not be delivered to the user.

this is my experience. after long time of try with services,  i make a solution with FCM and this work perfectly for me.

Comment: hey ronny how does one fire a fcm notification from one device to another. Cloud functions I suppose am I right?|
Have you done it before??

Comment: yes, you can use cloud functions.But there are ways to sent from Device to Device, just google it.

Answer (score 0):

How it should work is with a function that listens to a change in any state in your database.

Basically, you listen to a change in the desired reference, if that reference is changed you launch a function that will take the phone token ID of the sender and receiver and make a notification payload.

To understand better, please check this

[fcm-notifications](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications)

For example, at your use case, I would do it like this

First I send a message to a user, then when I post that message into Firebase Database I trigger a function that takes the sender token ID and sends and triggers a function that takes that message and sends it to the receiver token ID as a notification payload.

The user who receives the message does not need to have the app in the foreground, it can be in the background or killed (be sure that the service of the app that connects to fcm keeps running)